# Can't write in sql table with parameters

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I want to write data in an sql table with the following code en then I get an error.

When I have look in my Visual Studio I can see that there is data in @p1, etc...

```
SqlCommand send = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO test(code,type,datum,uur,controller,fout,teller,omschrijving,graad,var1,var2,var3,var4,var5,var6,var7,var8,var9,var10,var11,var12,var13,var14,var15,var16,var17,var18,var19,var20,var21,var22,var23,var24,var25,var26,var27,var28,var29,var30,var31,var32,var33,var34,var35,var36,var37,var38,var39,var40)" + "values (@p1,@p2,@p3,@p4,@p5,@p6,@p7,@p8,@p9,@p10,@p11,@p12,@p13,@p14,@p15,@p16,@p17,@p18,@p19,@p20,@p21,@p22,@p23,@p24,@p25,@p26,@p27,@p28,@p29,@p30,@p31,@p32,@p33,@p34,@p35,@p36,@p37,@p38,@p39,@p40,@p41,@p42,@p43,@p44,@p45,@p46,@p47,@p48,@p49)", connection);
       while (foutinformatie[0, lusteller] != null)          //zolang uitvoeren als er data is
        {

            //rij per rij in tabel plaatsensd
            key = foutinformatie[0, lusteller] + "/" + foutinformatie[1, lusteller] + "/" + foutinformatie[2, lusteller] + "/" + foutinformatie[3, lusteller] + "/" + foutinformatie[4, lusteller];
            send.Parameters.Clear();
            SqlParameter myParam1 = new SqlParameter("@p1", SqlDbType.Text);
            myParam1.Value = key;
            SqlParameter myParam2 = new SqlParameter("@p2", SqlDbType.Text);
            myParam2.Value = foutinformatie[0, lusteller];
            SqlParameter myParam3 = new SqlParameter("@p3", SqlDbType.Text);
            myParam3.Value = foutinformatie[1, lusteller];
            SqlParameter myParam4 = new SqlParameter("@p4", SqlDbType.Text);
            myParam4.Value = foutinformatie[2, lusteller];
            SqlParameter myParam5 = new SqlParameter("@p5", SqlDbType.Text);
            myParam5.Value = foutinformatie[3, lusteller];
            SqlParameter myParam6 = new SqlParameter("@p6", SqlDbType.Text);
            myParam6.Value = foutinformatie[4, lusteller];
            SqlParameter myParam7 = new SqlParameter("@p7", SqlDbType.Text);
            myParam7.Value = foutinformatie[5, lusteller];
            SqlParameter myParam8 = new SqlParameter("@p8", SqlDbType.Text);
            myParam8.Value = foutinformatie[6, lusteller];
            SqlParameter myParam9 = new SqlParameter("@p9", SqlDbType.Text);
            myParam9.Value = foutinformatie[7, lusteller];
            SqlParameter myParam10 = new SqlParameter("@p10", SqlDbType.Text);
            myParam10.Value = foutinformatie[8, lusteller];
            SqlParameter myParam11 = new SqlParameter("@p11", SqlDbType.Text);
            myParam11.Value = foutinformatie[9, lusteller];
            SqlParameter myParam12 = new SqlParameter("@p12", SqlDbType.Text);
            myParam12.Value = foutinformatie[10, lusteller];
            SqlParameter myParam13 = new SqlParameter("@p13", SqlDbType.Text);
            myParam13.Value = foutinformatie[11, lusteller];
            SqlParameter myParam14 = new SqlParameter("@p14", SqlDbType.Text);
            myParam14.Value = foutinformatie[12, lusteller];
            SqlParameter myParam15 = new SqlParameter("@p15", SqlDbType.Text);
            myParam15.Value = foutinformatie[13, lusteller];
            SqlParameter myParam16 = new SqlParameter("@p16", SqlDbType.Text);
            myParam16.Value = foutinformatie[14, lusteller];
            SqlParameter myParam17 = new SqlParameter("@p17", SqlDbType.Text);
            myParam17.Value = foutinformatie[15, lusteller];
            SqlParameter myParam18 = new SqlParameter("@p18", SqlDbType.Text);
            myParam18.Value = foutinformatie[16, lusteller];
            SqlParameter myParam19 = new SqlParameter("@p19", SqlDbType.Text);
            myParam19.Value = foutinformatie[17, lusteller];
            SqlParameter myParam20 = new SqlParameter("@p20", SqlDbType.Text);
            myParam20.Value = foutinformatie[18, lusteller];
            SqlParameter myParam21 = new SqlParameter("@p21", SqlDbType.Text);
            myParam21.Value = foutinformatie[19, lusteller];
            SqlParameter myParam22 = new SqlParameter("@p22", SqlDbType.Text);
            myParam22.Value = foutinformatie[20, lusteller];
            SqlParameter myParam23 = new SqlParameter("@p23", SqlDbType.Text);
            myParam23.Value = foutinformatie[21, lusteller];
            SqlParameter myParam24 = new SqlParameter("@p24", SqlDbType.Text);
            myParam24.Value = foutinformatie[22, lusteller];
            SqlParameter myParam25 = new SqlParameter("@p25", SqlDbType.Text);
            myParam25.Value = foutinformatie[23, lusteller];
            SqlParameter myParam26 = new SqlParameter("@p26", SqlDbType.Text);
            myParam26.Value = foutinformatie[24, lusteller];
            SqlParameter myParam27 = new SqlParameter("@p27", SqlDbType.Text);
            myParam27.Value = foutinformatie[25, lusteller];
            SqlParameter myParam28 = new SqlParameter("@p28", SqlDbType.Text);
            myParam28.Value = foutinformatie[26, lusteller];
            SqlParameter myParam29 = new SqlParameter("@p29", SqlDbType.Text);
            myParam29.Value = foutinformatie[27, lusteller];
            SqlParameter myParam30 = new SqlParameter("@p30", SqlDbType.Text);
            myParam30.Value = foutinformatie[28, lusteller];
            SqlParameter myParam31 = new SqlParameter("@p31", SqlDbType.Text);
            myParam31.Value = foutinformatie[29, lusteller];
            SqlParameter myParam32 = new SqlParameter("@p32", SqlDbType.Text);
            myParam32.Value = foutinformatie[30, lusteller];
            SqlParameter myParam33 = new SqlParameter("@p33", SqlDbType.Text);
            myParam33.Value = foutinformatie[31, lusteller];
            SqlParameter myParam34 = new SqlParameter("@p34", SqlDbType.Text);
            myParam34.Value = foutinformatie[32, lusteller];
            SqlParameter myParam35 = new SqlParameter("@p35", SqlDbType.Text);
            myParam35.Value = foutinformatie[33, lusteller];
            SqlParameter myParam36 = new SqlParameter("@p36", SqlDbType.Text);
            myParam36.Value = foutinformatie[34, lusteller];
            SqlParameter myParam37 = new SqlParameter("@p37", SqlDbType.Text);
            myParam37.Value = foutinformatie[35, lusteller];
            SqlParameter myParam38 = new SqlParameter("@p38", SqlDbType.Text);
            myParam38.Value = foutinformatie[36, lusteller];
            SqlParameter myParam39 = new SqlParameter("@p39", SqlDbType.Text);
            myParam39.Value = foutinformatie[37, lusteller];
            SqlParameter myParam40 = new SqlParameter("@p40", SqlDbType.Text);
            myParam40.Value = foutinformatie[38, lusteller];
            SqlParameter myParam41 = new SqlParameter("@p41", SqlDbType.Text);
            myParam41.Value = foutinformatie[39, lusteller];
            SqlParameter myParam42 = new SqlParameter("@p42", SqlDbType.Text);
            myParam42.Value = foutinformatie[40, lusteller];
            SqlParameter myParam43 = new SqlParameter("@p43", SqlDbType.Text);
            myParam43.Value = foutinformatie[41, lusteller];
            SqlParameter myParam44 = new SqlParameter("@p44", SqlDbType.Text);
            myParam44.Value = foutinformatie[42, lusteller];
            SqlParameter myParam45 = new SqlParameter("@p45", SqlDbType.Text);
            myParam45.Value = foutinformatie[43, lusteller];
            SqlParameter myParam46 = new SqlParameter("@p46", SqlDbType.Text);
            myParam46.Value = foutinformatie[44, lusteller];
            SqlParameter myParam47 = new SqlParameter("@p47", SqlDbType.Text);
            myParam47.Value = foutinformatie[45, lusteller];
            SqlParameter myParam48 = new SqlParameter("@p48", SqlDbType.Text);
            myParam48.Value = foutinformatie[46, lusteller];
            SqlParameter myParam49 = new SqlParameter("@p49", SqlDbType.Text);
            myParam49.Value = foutinformatie[47, lusteller];

            send.Parameters.Add(myParam1);
            send.Parameters.Add(myParam2);
            send.Parameters.Add(myParam3);
            send.Parameters.Add(myParam4);
            send.Parameters.Add(myParam5);
            send.Parameters.Add(myParam6);
            send.Parameters.Add(myParam7);
            send.Parameters.Add(myParam8);
            send.Parameters.Add(myParam9);
            send.Parameters.Add(myParam10);
            send.Parameters.Add(myParam11);
            send.Parameters.Add(myParam12);
            send.Parameters.Add(myParam13);
            send.Parameters.Add(myParam14);
            send.Parameters.Add(myParam15);
            send.Parameters.Add(myParam16);
            send.Parameters.Add(myParam17);
            send.Parameters.Add(myParam18);
            send.Parameters.Add(myParam19);
            send.Parameters.Add(myParam20);
            send.Parameters.Add(myParam21);
            send.Parameters.Add(myParam22);
            send.Parameters.Add(myParam23);
            send.Parameters.Add(myParam24);
            send.Parameters.Add(myParam25);
            send.Parameters.Add(myParam26);
            send.Parameters.Add(myParam27);
            send.Parameters.Add(myParam28);
            send.Parameters.Add(myParam29);
            send.Parameters.Add(myParam30);
            send.Parameters.Add(myParam31);
            send.Parameters.Add(myParam32);
            send.Parameters.Add(myParam33);
            send.Parameters.Add(myParam34);
            send.Parameters.Add(myParam35);
            send.Parameters.Add(myParam36);
            send.Parameters.Add(myParam37);
            send.Parameters.Add(myParam38);
            send.Parameters.Add(myParam39);
            send.Parameters.Add(myParam40);
            send.Parameters.Add(myParam41);
            send.Parameters.Add(myParam42);
            send.Parameters.Add(myParam43);
            send.Parameters.Add(myParam44);
            send.Parameters.Add(myParam45);
            send.Parameters.Add(myParam46);
            send.Parameters.Add(myParam47);
            send.Parameters.Add(myParam48);
            send.Parameters.Add(myParam49);
            try
            {
                int pos = Array.IndexOf(keys, key);
                if (pos == -1)
                {
                    connection.Open();
                    send.ExecuteNonQuery();
                 connection.Close();
                }
                else
                {

                }


            }
            catch
            {
                connection.Close();
               // MessageBox.Show("Can not open connection ! ");
            }

            lusteller = lusteller + 1;
        }
    }
```

Error:

> The parameterized query '(@p1 text,@p2 text,@p3 text,@p4 text,@p5 text,@p6 text,@p7 text,' expects the parameter '@p9', which was not supplied.

Comment: Please read [FAQ] and [ask], specially http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10647/how-do-i-write-a-good-title

Comment: I recognise this code... Ah, yep. [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15944542/error-with-writing-sql) has remarkably similar code snippets.

Comment: but there was the problem that there was non send.parameters.Clear() . In this code is this already excist

Answer (score 0):

Do you have nullable columns in your database? That could be the problem. If the value is null, you have to explicitly pass DBNull.Value. If you do not, the parameter may not be recognized correctly and reported as missing. You could do the assignment as following:

```
myParamX.Value = foutinformatie[0, lusteller] ?? DBNull.Value;
```

I would also strongly recommend you to create the parameters in a more efficient way. First, create all parameters for the command ONCE before you execute it and call `send.Prepare()`.
Than in a loop set your values for each row and execute the command. This is way more efficient.

```
connection.Open();

SqlCommand send = new SqlCommand(
    "INSERT INTO test(code,type,datum,uur,controller,fout,teller,omschrijving,graad,var1,var2,var3,var4,var5,var6,var7,var8,var9,var10,var11,var12,var13,var14,var15,var16,var17,var18,var19,var20,var21,var22,var23,var24,var25,var26,var27,var28,var29,var30,var31,var32,var33,var34,var35,var36,var37,var38,var39,var40)" + 
    "values (@p1,@p2,@p3,@p4,@p5,@p6,@p7,@p8,@p9,@p10,@p11,@p12,@p13,@p14,@p15,@p16,@p17,@p18,@p19,@p20,@p21,@p22,@p23,@p24,@p25,@p26,@p27,@p28,@p29,@p30,@p31,@p32,@p33,@p34,@p35,@p36,@p37,@p38,@p39,@p40,@p41,@p42,@p43,@p44,@p45,@p46,@p47,@p48,@p49)", 
    connection);

for (int i = 1; i <= 49; i++)
{
    send.Parameters.Add("@p" + i, SqlDbType.Text);
}

// prepare command (see documentation)
send.Prepare();

//zolang uitvoeren als er data is
while (foutinformatie[0, lusteller] != null)          
{
    //rij per rij in tabel plaatsensd
    key = foutinformatie[0, lusteller] + "/" +
        foutinformatie[1, lusteller] + "/" +
        foutinformatie[2, lusteller] + "/" +
        foutinformatie[3, lusteller] + "/" + 
        foutinformatie[4, lusteller];

    send.Parameters[0].Value = key;

    // assign values in a loop with regarding DBNull
    for (int i = 1; i < 49; i++)
    {
        send.Parameters[i].Value = foutinformatie[i-1, lusteller] ?? DBNull.Value;
    }

    send.ExecuteNonQuery();

    lusteller = lusteller + 1;
}
```

I did not run this code, maybe there is still some index offset problem. It should only demonstrate how to solve this more elegant.